# Why does IE 11 javascript strips spaces in value method?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

When having the option value of "ø- &" in a select tag and displaying the selected value in an alert IE 11 (11.0.9600.17126) seems to strip spaces and displays it as "ø-&" do you know why?

HTML:

```
<select id="companies">
       <option>ø- &</option>
       <option>ø- &amp;</option>
       <option>&oslash;- &amp;</option>
</select>
<button onclick="javascript:alert(document.getElementById('companies').value);">TEST</button>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aK35t/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply because you're reading the value of the option - but spaces aren't really valid inside the value. Instead, you want to read the *text*:

```
document.getElementById('companies')
.options[document.getElementById('companies').selectedIndex].text
```

However, you shouldn't rely on automatic "text to value" anyway. If you manually set the value of the option, it will work fine with your original code as well:

```
<select id="companies">
    <option value="ø- &amp;">ø- &amp;</option>
</select>
<button onclick="alert(document.getElementById('companies').value);">GET</button>
```

You'll most likely have some ID in the option value anyway, though - so if you want to get the text in javascript, use the snippet way above (or use jQuery's `text()`).

Comment: Using `value` attributes indeed fixes the problem, but spaces *are* valid, and it is a bug in IE 11 (not present e.g. in IE 10) that they are stripped off (when constructing the `value` property of `option` from its content, in the absence of a `value` attribute).

Comment: The IE 11 bug seems to depend on the presence of non-ASCII data in the `option` value, see the bug report [IE11 option.value returns mangled data when value contains HTML extended characters](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/888189/ie11-option-value-returns-mangled-data-when-value-contains-html-extended-characters).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It's not as simple as that. As the HTML5 spec says, `The text IDL attribute, on getting, must return the value of the textContent IDL attribute on the element, with leading and trailing whitespace stripped, and with any sequences of two or more space characters replaced by a single U+0020 SPACE character. On setting, it must act as if the textContent IDL attribute on the element had been set to the new value.` So it probably is a bug, but a lot more complex bug than it seems (e.g. using `abc def` preserves the space, and so does `č&nbsp;-&amp;`). It's quite tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to lie in your multi byte characters (ø, æ). Perhaps you can force the web page to use utf8 encoding?

Jquery somehow fixes that problem.

```
function getCompaniesValue() {
    alert($("#companies").val());
}
```

Gives the correct result.

Comment: Have tried with utf8 that is not working. Ive tried with jquery 1.7.1 that does not work. What version are you using?

Comment: @kasperxb: using Jquery 1.11. Update on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aK35t/15/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE 11 to test that, but for me it seems like an encoding problem. You should try to use the correct HTML entity to do that :

```
<select id="companies">
    <option>&oslash;- &amp;</option>
    <option>&oslash;- &</option>
</select>
<button onclick="javascript:alert(document.getElementById('companies').value);">TEST</button>
```

Comment: Tried with &oslash; but is is not working! Updated the jsfiddle.