# IE wrongly sends request body in ISO-8859-1

Tags: http, internet-explorer, utf-8, character-encoding, http-headers

IE 11 sends request body like this:

> -----------------------------7e5314b502b0 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="add_field_ÐÐ¾Ð¼ÐµÑ ÑÐµÐ»ÐµÑÐ¾Ð½Ð°
> (ÑÐ¾ÑÐ¾Ð²ÑÐ¹)"
>
> aasvechn
> -----------------------------7e5314b502b0 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="add_field_ÐÐ¾Ð»Ð¶Ð½Ð¾ÑÑÑ"
>
> Ð¼ÐµÐ½ÐµÐ´Ð¶ÐµÑ
> -----------------------------7e5314b502b0 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="add_field_Ð¤ÐÐ ÑÑÐºÐ¾Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð¸ÑÐµÐ»Ñ"
>
> aasvechn
> -----------------------------7e5314b502b0 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="add_field_ÐÐ¾Ð¼ÐµÑ Ð½Ð°Ð·Ð½Ð°ÑÐµÐ½Ð¸Ñ Ð² Oracle"
>
> aasvechn
> -----------------------------7e5314b502b0 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="add_field_Ð¡ÑÐ¾Ðº ÑÐ°Ð±Ð¾ÑÑ Ð² ÐÐ¾Ð¼Ð¿Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ð¸ "
>
> 0-3Ð¼ÐµÑ

It's supposed be cyrillic characters. I tried `accept-charset="utf-8"` in the form and I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in the document header. [Request/response header looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGzQ0.png).

Whats more important, is that IE misses whitespaces. For example, `0-3 мес` suddenly transforms into `0-3Ð¼ÐµÑ`. I tried to convert it manually with converter, and whitespaces was on their places. Any help will be much appreciated

**UPD:**

As I figured out, missing spaces is [IE related bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525102/why-does-ie-11-javascript-strips-spaces-in-value-method) with invalid text-to-value transform. I'm still don't know why IE prints request in ISO-8859-1, but in fact it is correctly appears as UTF-8 on the server side, so `charset=UTF-8` worked correctly

Comment: Are you using Unicode fonts on your site? If not, it may cause this issue. See this helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005301/10309381). Further, you can also refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/browsers/wrong-character-set-for-html-page) may give you some additional information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I figured out, missing spaces is [IE related bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525102/why-does-ie-11-javascript-strips-spaces-in-value-method) with invalid text-to-value transform. I'm still don't know why IE prints request in ISO-8859-1, but in fact it is correctly appears as UTF-8 on the server side, so `charset=UTF-8` worked correctly

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As I figured out, missing spaces is [IE related bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525102/why-does-ie-11-javascript-strips-spaces-in-value-method) with invalid text-to-value transform. I'm still don't know why IE prints request in ISO-8859-1, but in fact it is correctly appears as UTF-8 on the server side, so `charset=UTF-8` worked correctly